# How did Davros survive the events of Journey's End?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

In the 10th Doctor episode, "Journey's End," Davros is seemingly killed. However, he returns in the 12th Doctor two-parter "The Magician's Apprentice"/"The Witch's Familiar" with no explanation for his reappearance. How did he survive/escape the events of "Journey's End?"

Comment: Oh, it was quite clear he would return one day. Davros has been seemingly killed so often, we already knew that something as trivial as a planet blowing up wouldn't kill him. I don't know how he did it this time; does it matter? Maybe he cloned himself.

Comment: It might have just been a dream?

Comment: Wibbly wobbly, timey wimey, etc.

Comment: Death can't be permanent in a show based on time travel.

Comment: "Emergency Temporal Shift", I believe...

Answer (score -1):

**Davros in *the magician’s apprentice* and *the witch’s familiar* had not experienced the events of *the journey’s end***

It’s not stated that Davros first experienced the events of the journey’s end before he experienced the events of the magician’s apprentice. The doctor is a time traveller. The tenth doctor might have met davros after the twelfth doctor.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this theory?

Answer (score -2):

Teleportation. Knowing that he'd need to escape the Daleks succeed in their plan to destroy all life except them and Davros, Davros installed an emergency teleport in his chair to escape preserving his life and knowing the Daleks wouldn't come after him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this theory?  Good answers are more than just what feels right to you; they have references to canon sources to back them up.